# Getting Error - 'Inconsistency in usage of column' while partitioning a table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have got a table `ee_company_product_listings_par` which has got many columns including `cplc_id` and `marketplaceID`.

This is the DDL of the table:-

```
ee_company_product_listings_par | CREATE TABLE `ee_company_product_listings_par` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `company_product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `feed_dump_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `listing_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sku` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mrp` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `selling_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `merchant_payout` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `commission` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `commission_service_tax` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `pmt_gateway_charge` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_local` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_zonal` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_national` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `site_uid` varchar(200) DEFAULT '-',
    `listing_ref_number` varchar(200) DEFAULT '-',
    `UID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `marketplaceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `inventory_live` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `update_cpl_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `sku_corrected` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `cplisting_entry_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `weight` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `length` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `height` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `width` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cplc_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `mp_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `process_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `host_ip` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `color` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `size` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `identifier` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mp_brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`cplc_id`,`marketplaceID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21474383 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Range of `cplc_id` is from 0-10000
Range of `marketplaceID` is from 0-100

I want to create Range partitions on the basis of these two columns.

This was the query I am running:-

```
alter table ee_company_product_listings_par partition by range columns (cplc_id, marketplaceID) (
PARTITION p500_5 VALUES LESS THAN (500, 5),
PARTITION p500_10 VALUES LESS THAN (500,10),
PARTITION p1000_5 VALUES LESS THAN (1000,5),
PARTITION p1000_10 VALUES LESS THAN (1000,10),
partition pmax values less than MAXVALUE
);
```

This is the error I am getting:-

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): Inconsistency in usage of column lists for partitioning near 'MAXVALUE
)' at line 4
```

Can someone help to find what is the problem in the query. Searched all over the internet but didn't find any solution. There might be some silly mistake as I am totally new to partitioning.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error; use this:

```
VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE)
```

What do you expect to gain from `PARTITIONing`?  What `SELECTs` will benefit?

Comment: Thanks Rick. Basically the number of rows has crossed 100 million and the SELECTs are totally based on those two columns (cplc_id, marketplaceID) so thought partitioning will give significant increase in the efficiency of all the operations related to the table. 

What do you suggest ??

Comment: What does the `WHERE` clause look like?  If it is simply  `WHERE cplc_id = constant AND marketplaceID = constant`, then `INDEX (cplc_id, marketplaceID)` is better than partitioning.  If some other `WHERE`, let's see it.

Comment: Yeah..that can be done but many times we have to delete on the basis of those two columns. So in that case I think partitioning will perform better. 
Writes will also take much time without partitioning as the sizes of indices would be very large on such a big table but after partitioning the indices will be on each partition only, so the writes will also be more efficient. 

Please correct me If am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Please show us a typical `DELETE`.  Your argument in favor of partitioning does not how water for the sample I gave.  And...  Updating a huge index is only slightly slower than updating a tiny one -- read-modify-write a single block.  (The difference comes in locating and caching that one block.)

Comment: A typical delete would be like `delete from ee_company_product_listings_par where cplc_id = ? and marketplaceID = ?`. Wouldn't that be fast in a partitioned table?

Comment: With the suggested index, it might be slightly faster with a non-partitioned table.  With partitioning, first the partition(s) needs to be identified ("pruning"); then the index in the partition(s) needs to be drilled into (BTree lookup).  The BTree effort is virtually the same in partitioning versus non-partitioning.

Comment: Ohh... So that means there won't be much improvement from partitioning? Then why people suggest partitoning on such big tables?
And btw really thanks for all the insights provided by you!!

Comment: My [_blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) on partitioning lists the only 4 use cases where partitioning improves performance.  I do not detect that your use case is any of the 4.  Novices see Partitioning as a panacea.

Comment: That was really an eye-opener Rick. Thanks for sharing such useful knowledge. 
And that's really true that I was seeing partitioning as the ultimate solution but it should not be like that.
Will take care from now and try to go more deep into partitioning as well as other topics related to mySql and your website seems a great resource for that. :)

Comment: Thanks for the praise.  My blogs are aimed at the users of forums like this.  And they come reading thousands of questions and seeing patterns.  Raw novices have no clue of indexing.  Medium novices think Partitioning is a panacea.  After that, the patterns are more subtle.

Comment: Another pattern:  `FLOAT(m,n)` involves 2 roundings; it should never be used.  Either use `DECIMAL(m,n)` to get precisely n decimal places (usually for dollars and cents), or use plain `FLOAT` to get about 7 significant digits (for scientific use).

Comment: Ohh!! So those 2 roundings are bad from the point of view of data consistency or efficiency of the I/Os on DB. Beacuse we have used `FLOAT(m,n)` at so many places in our system, so should we replace all of them with `DECIMAL(m,n) ?? :|

Comment: Inserting into `FLOAT(m,n)` rounds to n decimal places (in decimal) and converts decimal to binary for storing.  `DECIMAL(m,n)` stores in decimal, so it only needs one rounding.  Storing into plain `FLOAT` simply converts to binary.

Comment: So that's extra effort from the DB side while using `FLOAT(m,n)`. Will try to update our existing system and definitely take care in the future!!